# SQL multiple column IN selections

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which needs rows removing where two other columns match.
So for example:

```
Apples  |  Size   |  Colour  | Juiced
 1      |   big   |   red    |  Yes
 2      |   small |   green  |  No
```

I want the query to remove all rows that have size big, and colour red, and juiced.

the problem is I need to find out size and colour from the same table (so cannot use left join) but I require this table to be used in the IN statement.
I'm attempting to use IN to select rows like:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE (Juiced <> 'No') OR
(Juiced LIKE 'yes' AND (Size, Colour IN (SELECT Size, Colour FROM table WHERE blah=blah)));
```

SQL does not allow two variables to be matched within the table at once using IN, so is there any way I can get both Size and Colour to be recognised by the IN statement?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Bridge Doesn't look like there's anything missing to me, but possible it was edited.

Comment: yes apologies, I edited it!

Comment: Can't you `JOIN` your tables together and test the appropriate columns?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes in fact most of the query has changed since I started writing my pointers, sort of invalid now!

Comment: Although DJB, if you're going to use LIKE without any wildcard characters, may as well use equals! :)

Comment: I am pretty sure that in `(Juiced <> 'No') OR (Juiced LIKE 'yes' AND ..` the first clause of your `OR` expression is already including everything that could be added by the second half.

Comment: thanks Bridge, sorry for editing without indicating.. I realised I had not written the query right first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually - when you are thinking about **IN with multiple columns** your thinking about [EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/enus/library/ms188336(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table T
WHERE (Juiced <> 'No') OR (Juiced LIKE 'yes' AND 
                                            (EXISTS (SELECT Size, Colour 
                                                     FROM [table] A 
                                                     WHERE A.Apples = T.Apples AND
                                                           -- put your 'balhh here...')))
```

Comment: As said - you should also replace the `LIKE` with `=` in this case.

Comment: used this, and it solved it completely, thanks to all - made my understanding much better!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Size, Colour
    FROM anotherTable
    WHERE condition
) anotherTable ON table.Size = anotherTable.Size AND table.Colour = anotherTable.Colour
WHERE (Juiced <> 'No') -- should this be (Juiced = 'No')?
OR (Juiced LIKE 'yes' AND anotherTable.Size IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: haven't checked whether this works, as it is solved - but thank you!